# How to specify server side encryption for s3 put in pyspark?

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

Thanks to stackoverflow, i managed to copy hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar and aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar from maven repo into $SPARK_HOME/jars/ to get s3a:// going for reading from S3 buckets using pyspark (spark 2.2.0) on my ec2 linux instance.

> df=spark.read.option("header","true").csv("s3a://bucket/csv_file")

But I'm stuck at writing the transformed data back into s3 bucket with server side encryption enabled. As expected below action throws "Access Denied" as I haven't specified flag to enable server side encryption within pyspark execution env

> df.write.parquet("s3a://s3_bucket/output.parquet")

To verify, I wrote to a local file and uploaded to s3 bucket using -sse and this works fine

> aws s3 cp local_path s3://s3_bucket/ --sse

How do I enable server side encryption in pyspark similar to above?

**Note:** I did try adding "fs.s3a.enableServerSideEncryption true" to spark-default.conf and passing the same via --conf parameter of pyspark at start but no joy.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I understood after going through following Hadoop JIRAs - HADOOP-10675, HADOOP-10400, HADOOP-10568

Since fs/s3 is part of Hadoop following needs to be added into spark-default.conf if all S3 bucket puts in your estate is protected by SSE

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm AES256
```

And after adding this I was able to write successfully to S3 bucket protected by SSE (Server side encryption).

Answer (score 2):

Hope you already setup configuration with access-keys, secret-keys, enableServerSideEncryption and algorithm to be used for the encryption.

```
val hadoopConf = sc.hadoopConfiguration;
    hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
    hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", "xxx")
    hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", "xxx")
    hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.enableServerSideEncryption", "true")
    hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.serverSideEncryptionAlgorithm","AES256")
```

Enforces server side encryption

```
--emrfs Encryption=ServerSide,Args=[fs.s3.serverSideEncryptionAlgorithm=AES256].
```

Command :

./bin/spark-submit --verbose —jars lib/app.jar \

```
--master spark://master-amazonaws.com:7077  \
--class com.elsevier.spark.SparkSync \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Ds3service.server-side-encryption=AES256"
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingServerSideEncryption.html

Protecting Data Using Server-Side Encryption with Amazon S3-Managed Encryption Keys (SSE-S3)

Server-side encryption is about protecting data at rest. Server-side encryption with Amazon S3-managed encryption keys (SSE-S3) employs strong multi-factor encryption. Amazon S3 encrypts each object with a unique key. As an additional safeguard, it encrypts the key itself with a master key that it regularly rotates. Amazon S3 server-side encryption uses one of the strongest block ciphers available, 256-bit Advanced Encryption Standard (AES-256), to encrypt your data.

Amazon S3 supports bucket policies that you can use if you require server-side encryption for all objects that are stored in your bucket. For example, the following bucket policy denies upload object (s3:PutObject) permission to everyone if the request does not include the x-amz-server-side-encryption header requesting server-side encryption.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "PutObjPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyIncorrectEncryptionHeader",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YourBucket/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YourBucket/*",
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Note the config options listed here are for EMR only, and its s3 connector; the fs.s3a ones for ASF hadoop are different. Everything related to setting security options on a bucket are valid on both —and the best way to verify that the options are being picked up. If you can't write to the bucket, it means the encryption setup failed