# Errors writing file to s3 - pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I'm getting some strange errors when trying to write files to s3 after all the processing is done. 
I am wondering whether the memory allocation has anything to do with this.
Any suggestions will be helpful. 
I am running Spark 2.1.0 in Standalone mode.

The errors are as follows:

```
17/09/26 15:50:27 ERROR Utils: Aborting task
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.next(InterruptibleIterator.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)

  ....
  Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:169)
    ... 21 more
17/09/26 15:50:28 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Job job_20170926152633_0010 aborted.
17/09/26 15:50:28 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 270.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 6680)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at 

 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter
  $.org$apache$
  spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$
   $executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:204)
    at 


.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$3.\
apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:128)
```

The code that writes the file to s3 is as follows:

```
            df.write.format("parquet") \
            .option("x-amz-server-side-encryption", "AES256") \
            .mode("append") \
            .save(s3_path)
```

Comment: Could you give first a try writing to s3 without encryption and append mode like this `df.write.parquet(s3_path)`

Comment: Check this link which might be helpful in enabling the encryption.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461299/how-to-specify-server-side-encryption-for-s3-put-in-pyspark

Answer (score 0):

I am using this simplest way for writing the file on S3 so try this. if you need this option `.option("x-amz-server-side-encryption", "AES256")` so you can add it.

```
       df.write.mode("append").parquet(s3_path)
```

I am using spark 2.0.1 version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that .`option("x-amz-server-side-encryption", "AES256")`. The `.option()` command sets a property for the DF writer task, rather than set an HTTP header on the upload. You need to look in the documentation of your s3 connector (EMR or Apache Hadoop's) and its setttings.

At the same time, I don't think it causes the crash. It'll just be ignored.

Paste the whole stack.